# WebSocket connect another websocket in this browser

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have my browser connecting to system hardware application at localhost using websocket. Sometimes this hardware application disabled, so I want to emulate this hardware application directly in the browser by creating another websocket. How can I do this?

I tried to emulate it by creating two websockets simultaneously, something like this:

```
socket1 = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')
socket2 = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')
```

But this doesn't work. How can I establish this connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a mocking framework to mock the server in this situation. I have succesfully used [`mock-socket`](https://github.com/thoov/mock-socket) to do exactly this, eg. (quoting example from README.md):

```
var mockServer = new MockServer('ws://localhost:8080');
mockServer.on('connection', function(server) {
    server.on('message', function(data) {
        server.send('hello world!');
    } );
} );
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers,